# Is it possible to buy songs from iTunes through my tvOS application

Tags: swift, itunes, tvos, itunes-api

I have implemenetd to play iTunes songs from my tvOS application. I wants to give the feature to `purchase songs` from my application for this i have following code -

```
var iTunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/crazy-naked-girls/id310568758?i=310568759&uo=4&at=xxxxxxWa&app=itunes";

if let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: iTunesLink as String) {
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appStoreURL) == true) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appStoreURL)
    }
}
```

but this line `UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appStoreURL)` always giving `false` value.

Comment: dude, can you try itms link than a http one ?

Comment: @thndrkiss 'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/album/crazy-naked-girls/id310568758?i=310568759&uo=4&at=xxxxxxWa&app=itunes' redirects me on itms store, I wants to redirect on iTunes store, so that i can buy songs from iTunes.